# Is there an automated way to determine if the system createdby field is included in reports and which ones

Tags: apex, reporting

- Is there an automated way to determine if the system CreatedBy field
  is included in reports and which ones?

OR

- do we need to do a manual review of all reports to determine which need to change?

I am using below code to find any

```java
// Get the report ID
List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM Report where 
    DeveloperName = 'Closed_Sales_This_Quarter'];
String reportId = (String)reportList.get(0).get('Id');

// Run a report
Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId);

// Get the report metadata
Reports.ReportMetadata rm = results.getReportMetadata();
System.debug('Name: ' + rm.getName());
System.debug('ID: ' + rm.getId());
System.debug('Currency code: ' + rm.getCurrencyCode());
System.debug('Developer name: ' + rm.getDeveloperName());

// Get grouping info for first grouping
Reports.GroupingInfo gInfo = rm.getGroupingsDown()[0];
System.debug('Grouping name: ' + gInfo.getName());
System.debug('Grouping sort order: ' + gInfo.getSortOrder());
System.debug('Grouping date granularity: ' + gInfo.getDateGranularity());

// Get aggregates
System.debug('First aggregate: ' + rm.getAggregates()[0]);
System.debug('Second aggregate: ' + rm.getAggregates()[1]);

// Get detail columns
System.debug('Detail columns: ' + rm.getDetailColumns());

// Get report format
System.debug('Report format: ' + rm.getReportFormat());
```

But I am receiving below error

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Comment: Can you pl share stacktrace which shows the line num of the error?

Comment: Why not import all the report metadata into your IDE and do a search?

Comment: Should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use your IDE (VSCode, Illuminated Cloud 2, etc) or even Workbench and download all metadata for Metadata Type `Report`

Then use the IDE's text search features (or grep) to find all files (each Report will be a file) where `CreatedDate` is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume every report is going to have the details you're looking at - specifically, in your case, `GroupingInfo` and `getAggregates`. If there's no grouping done or no summary fields, the list returned will be *empty* so trying to *directly* interact with data that doesn't exist by specifying the value (`[0]` or `[1]`) will throw that error you're receiving

```java
//If there's no groupings, will be empty and will throw error
Reports.GroupingInfo gInfo = rm.getGroupingsDown()[0];
...
System.debug('First aggregate: ' + rm.getAggregates()[0]);
//In this case, this'll throw the error if there's only one summary field
System.debug('Second aggregate: ' + rm.getAggregates()[1]);
```

You seem to be only getting row groupings, be aware there's also column groupings:

- [getGroupingsDown()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_reportmetadata.htm#apex_Reports_ReportMetadata_getGroupingsDown) refers to the row groupingss
- [getGroupingsAcross()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_reportmetadata.htm#:%7E:text=Type%3A%20String-,getGroupingsAcross,-()) refers to column groupings.

Otherwise, you'll need to do relevant empty checks or utilize for loops (no action if empty) across all your lists as there can exist reports with no filters and/or groupings

```java
List<Reports.GroupingInfo> columnGroupings = rm.getGroupingsAcross();
List<Reports.GroupingInfo> rowGroupings = rm.getGroupingDown();


for(Reports.GroupingInfo columnGroup : columnGroupings){
    if(columnGroup.getName() == 'CREATED'){
        //stop code, return true, whatever your goal is
    }
}

//do same for row groupings

...

List<String> reportAggregates = rm.getAggregates();
for(String reportAggregate : reportAggregates){
   //check
}
```